# How to remove NULL values from SELECT SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, isnullorempty

I have been working on this query for some time and have been unable to determine whether or not it can or cannot be done from my research. To date I have tried many versions of the query below with AND, OR, NOT IN - EXISTS but always get a sub-query error ERROR: sub-select returns 3 columns - expected 1.

I have also tried running them as separate queries, then into a for loop, appending both to a list and using the sorted function in the python program. Except it prints out as two separate lists in long form instead of with a \n after each result.

I have also tried in a for loop using if 'middle' or i[1] = None: print i[0], i[2] and i4 but, I get an error which i cannot find or recall.  I also tried turning the data into a dict and parsing it with the field-names i.e if 'middle' == None: print('first', 'last', 'birth'.

Anyhow its 6:53am.  I'm exhausted and I've been up all night with this and have to be at work in an hour or so.  I don't want the answer but would hope Ito learn if this is at least possible to do with the SELECT query or if I have to split it into part SELECT query and part parsing the None value out through python script.

```
    SELECT first, middle, last, birth 
    FROM students 
    WHERE house = 'Gryffindor' AND middle IS NOT NULL 
    OR (SELECT first, last, birth 
    FROM students 
    WHERE house = 'Gryffindor' AND middle IS NULL) 
    ORDER BY last, first '''
```

Comment: Hi Chris, it is possible.  I don't have too much time to give a comprehensive answer right now, but perhaps a quick look at this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And the or condition should result in either true or false.

Comment: You have an interesting diary on frustration.  I'm rather clueless on what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, a frustrating evening for sure.  I submitted this post mainly to confirm that it could be done through the SELECT query.  Completed it this evening once James S confirmed it was actually possible.  Many thanks!! - Great function for NULL values                                      
             SELECT first, COALESCE(middle,''), last, birth